# When to use "nude" and when "naked"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, formality, connotation

The question is quite clear.

Is there any difference (semantically or connotationally, if that's a word) between *nude* and *naked*? *Nude* seems more formal to me, but I'm not quite sure.

Interesting: 
Merriam-Webster link from naked, to nude

> Definition of NAKED
>   1. not covered by clothing : [nude](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nude)

Comment: Well, you can say appropriately, "He's in the nude," but you cannot say, "He's in the naked"!  You can say, "The artist is famous for his sensual nudes," but you cannot say, "The artist is famous for his sensual nakeds"!  Nude, then, does seem a bit more formal.  Its connotation has a "softer" edge to it, whereas "naked" is a bit edgier to the ear, perhaps because of the hard "k" sound.  Saying with astonishment "My goodness, he's completely naked!" seems quite appropriate, whereas "My goodness, he's completely nude!" does not.  It's hard to say why.

Comment: I don't know why--perhaps the *-ed* ending blocks it--but "nude" seems more *nounish* (or *nounable*).

Comment: "He's completely nude!" sounds fine to me. Might be a British English thing. "He's in the  nip" is equally fine :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

*Nude* is by and large used only to refer to the absence of clothing or any covering in general.

- Nude beaches
- Nude model

*Naked*, on the other hand, has far wider connotations than *nude*. You can look them up [here](http://thefreedictionary.com/naked).

- Naked eye
- Naked truth
- Naked to one's enemies

It's also worth noting that *naked* is a rather technical word in life sciences, which is not the case with *nude*.

Comment: In the U.S., we have nude furniture, meaning unfinished. In the U.K., they have the Naked Chef (simple food, by Jamie Oliver).

Comment: @Jim: Yes and I understand there is also nudity in law referring to cases where evidence is not required.

Comment: I hadn't heard that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jim: See [this link](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/nudity).

Comment: When used as adjectives to describe people, ‘nude’ usually implies complete nudity, whereas ‘naked’ seems often to be used for only partial nudity. I’ve been noticing more and more lately, but I don’t know if that’s because it’s a budding trend or just because I haven’t been paying attention before. But I often now hear people describing themselves as ‘naked’ when in fact they are wearing swimsuits or boxer briefs or something similar.

Comment: fantastic approach.

Answer (score 82):

### The Naked and the Nude

*Robert Graves*

For me, the naked and the nude
(By lexicographers construed
As synonyms that should express
The same deficiency of dress
Or shelter) stand as wide apart
As love from lies, or truth from art.

Lovers without reproach will gaze
On bodies naked and ablaze;
The Hippocratic eye will see
In nakedness, anatomy;
And naked shines the Goddess when
She mounts her lion among men.

The nude are bold, the nude are sly
To hold each treasonable eye.
While draping by a showman's trick
Their dishabille in rhetoric,
They grin a mock-religious grin
Of scorn at those of naked skin.

The naked, therefore, who compete
Against the nude may know defeat;
Yet when they both together tread
The briary pastures of the dead,
By Gorgons with long whips pursued,
How naked go the sometime nude!

Comment: Ahh!  Education and poetry in one answer! :-)

Comment: And note that he incorporates and answers *all* the other answers. If you want to know about language, go to the poets.

Comment: I'm a fan, Stoney! We need more evocative and imaginative replies like this. Go, Stoney!

Comment: -1 although it is quite fancy, it makes me lose focus while trying to grasp the gist :(

Comment: I have to go with Terry Li. It's a great poem, but it's not quite a good answer.

Comment: It may not be a "good" answer, but it is a brilliant answer. +1

Comment: This is a beautiful but, for many, entirely unhelpful answer. If someone has to ask what the difference is between *nude* and *naked*, they will probably have to ask a lot more questions just to understand the poem. This is an answer for people who don't need to ask the question.

Comment: @JohnY Are answers by experts, for experts not welcome on this stack exchange?

Comment: @user867: I don't think there is any policy against answers by experts for experts. But for me, the standard for whether an answer is a good one is whether it is helpful to the person asking the question, or anyone else who has the same question. By that standard, this answer is a rather poor one.

Comment: This answer is good for all the reasons people in the comments are saying it's not - it doesn't spoon feed you the answer.  Most poems, this being no exception, requires one to think critically to fully understand.  I appreciate that StoneyB is encouraging readers to participate in that practice.  Therefore, +1. :)

Comment: There are many ways to answer a question. Some are comprehended quickly, and others are more memorable. This is a very memorable answer to a common question. A Q&A site should embrace all valid answers, because by answering a question correctly in more than one way, you do more to cement the answer.

Answer (score 40):

An [article in The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/artanddesign/2006/feb/08/photography.art) summarises [Kenneth Clark's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Clark) explanation of the difference between *naked* and *nude*:

> It was the art historian Kenneth Clark who claimed there is a difference. **A naked human body is exposed, vulnerable, embarrassing**, he wrote in his 1956 book The Nude. "The word **'nude', on the other hand, carries, in educated usage, no uncomfortable overtone**. The vague image it projects into the mind is not of a huddled and defenceless body, but of a balanced, prosperous and confident body ... "

A [philosophy professor's summary](http://www.angelfire.com/ks3/tsader_philosophy/StewartBlocker_text/Kenneth_Clarks_The_Naked_and_the_Nude.html) of Clark's book includes the following points:

> The connotative differences between the nude and the naked:
>
> 1. To be naked suggests deprivation, i.e., deprived of clothes and embarrassed about it.
> 2. To be nude suggests a balanced, confident, prosperous body--no discomfort or embarrassment.
> 3. This difference suggests that the nude is an art form invented by fifth-century Greeks.

Answer (score 18):

The use of "nude" is virtually always to indicate that a human form lacks clothing. It is, in most usages, a statement of this simple truth, and so it generally has a more innocent, natural connotation. Because it refers specifically to human forms and cannot usually be used to describe anything else, it can be used as a noun: "a nude" is a person who is nude. A "nude beach" is an example of the word in this noun form; the beach itself isn't nude, it's instead a beach for nudes.

Again, because of the simplicity implied in the word, "nude" has an artistic connotation, as countless works of art depict the human form lacking clothing (at least in areas of the body that we typically conceal in Western culture), without the subjects seeming to be aware of this fact. They certainly do not draw attention to it themselves, although the artist might in the composition of the work.

"Naked" has the same technical definition of being "uncovered", but various idiomatic usages typically give the word a connotation of starkness; something "naked" has often been actively uncovered or exposed, when it is normally concealed; e.g. "the naked truth". This starkness implies an impropriety to the state; that something which is "naked" shouldn't be, because it normally isn't, and the intent of it being naked is to shock or embarrass; it's right there, in your face, daring you to do something about it. Other usages are clinical or technical; "the naked eye". The combination of these various usages give "naked" a "cold" connotation.

A third synonym, with similar general-purpose usage and starkness as "naked" but with a less negative connotation, is "bare". Again, the technical definition is basically "uncovered, unconcealed, exposed", but unlike "nude" or even "naked", almost anything can be bare. The connotation, then, is that it's not necessarily improper for something to be bare; it's more acceptable, however still somewhat stark, and the connotation is that this might not be a good long-term state of affairs for whatever is bare, but it's acceptable, at least for a time. For instance, bare (unfinished) wood.

Answer (score 10):

Nude is arty, while naked is dirty.

Comment: Reminds me of the old saw about nude means without clothes, nekked means nude and up to no good.

Comment: I think the quote you're looking for comes from Tom Robbins in *Skinny Legs and All*:  "Naked means you just don't have any clothes on. Nekkid means you don't have any clothes on and you're fixing to get into trouble."

Comment: can't agree. Naked is IMO pretty much synonymous with nude. Might be regional/cultural differences. And looking at search results for either, you get roughly the same percentage porn so the creators and customers of the porn industry certainly don't distinguish :) I'd rather reword it as "nude is a more formal term, naked more casual".

Comment: And _nekkid_ is nude but living in a mobile home in a cruddy trailer park.

Comment: To my mind, only kids could be *nekkid*. Up to no good very probably: it suggests mischief, but not anything dirty. It's not a word I think I'd apply to adults.

Comment: A quick perusal of the Internet suggests that this is a personal idiosyncrasy, and that other people certainly *do* use the word *nekkid* with sexual connotations. Must bear that in mind.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a strict distinction but, the trend in current usage appears to be:

- *naked* emphasises the *lack of clothes*.

  > Some people wear nightclothes in bed, but others prefer to sleep **naked**.
- *nude* emphasises the *body*.

  > Classical painters considered the **nude**, which celebrated the human form, the highest form of art.

Answer (score 8):

According to Larry Niven, *"Nude is artistic. Naked is defenseless."* I think this dovetails with KeithS's distinction.

Comment: or maybe better "nude is a state of dress, naked is a state of mind" :)

Comment: Of course this was a Larry Niven character, and Niven had a comment about people who confuse a character’s views with the author’s.

Answer (score 3):

When used to describe the state of absence of clothing:

*Nude* is the result of a deliberate, calm and considered act of removal, typically to reveal the body without, or with subdued, sexual connotation. Examples:

- A nude model (one who poses nude for an artist - there is nothing racy about it)
- A nude beach (where the complete lack of clothing is permitted)

*Naked* suggests an ill-considered, unexpected or sexually-suggestive absence of clothing

- He was caught naked (he didn't intend to be seen without clothing)
- The streaker was completely naked! (how naughty!)
- A naked man walked into the room (unexpected and unacceptable absence of clothing)
- They were caught naked in bed together (and we know exactly what they were up to)

Comment: In general naked does not suggest "an ill-considered, unexpected or sexually-suggestive absence of clothing".  Consider "I usually shower naked.", "In the changing room, I got naked, so I could try on some clothes.", "My doctor asked me to get naked for my physical.".

Comment: @emory But "naked" in your examples clearly signifies a deviation from the normal. You are naked under the shower or for a phyisical, but not elsewhere. A nudist on the other hand is naked everywhere. And he is not called a "nakedist" for just that difference in meaning.

Answer (score 3):

For me, naked implies shame, embarrassment, humiliation or premature or unwanted exposure of one's unclothed body. I take being nude to be a conscience choice that implies relaxation, being comfortable in one's own skin (with one's own nudity), the aesthetic beauty and grace
of the uncovered human body (particularly one that is physically fit and toned, male or female), etc.

For example, if someone is completely stripped of their clothing against their will, they are then left naked; but, if someone relaxes at home alone or with friends in a completely unclothed state (domestic and/or social nudism), because they and their friends feel more comfortable that way, then they are nude.  Just my personal opinion and point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, it's a matter of heritage.  "Naked" is rough and ready Anglo-Saxon, from "nacod", while "nude" is from Latin "nudus/a/um", and so can carry -- like it or not -- connotative differences that make it seem more formal.  In  a way we are lucky.  Most languages, particularly the romance languages, only have their words descended from "nudus/a/um", such as Spanish "desnudo/a", or Italian "nudo/a".  I had almost forgotten about the 
Robert Graves poem, which spells out one man's studied view of the differences in connotations.

Comment: And German has only *nackt* (although we have *Nudisten*, i.e. adherents of *Freikörperkultur*).

Comment: @CarstenS: nackt, nackert, nackig, splitternackt...maybe not Hochdeutsch, but certainly variation.

Answer (score 0):

Both words can have different connotations depending on how they're used, but they're not unique to that particular word. Both can be used sexually or matter-of-factly, for example.

Generally speaking, "nude" is softer/informal than "naked", which is generally more formal.

You wouldn't say, "he's a naked model", as it would seem demeaning. Being a "nude model" sounds far more polite.

Likewise, if you were being questioned by police about possible streaker activities, it would seem a little weird to be asked, "were you in the nude?" instead of "were you naked"?

Answer (score 0):

Nude mostly refers to *naked human figure* where  **naked**  implies the meaning  *without clothes*. Naked - in a broader connotation refers to a meaning of *without  usual covering*

```
You may be nude or naked.
```

but

```
You may feel naked

You may have naked emotions
```

Answer (score 0):

*naked* implies that a person is unprotected or vulnerable, unadorned while *nude* means just unclothed.

> Linda captures **naked** Paul's gentle joy... (the BNC)
>
> Half **nude**, she held onto a big, round glass ball... (the BNC)

The BNC (British National Corpus) provides that *naked* is used 1878 times, *nude* - 403 times.

The noun of *nude* has a different form *nudity*.

Answer (score -2):

**Nude.** You can use this word as both an adjective (attribute of something) and a noun (about place, people, or time)

But, **naked** can only be used as an adjective.

There is not so much difference, I think.

Comment: Anything to support your answer? According to dics *"nude"* as a noun means *a naked human figure, typically as the subject of a painting, sculpture, or photograph.*

Answer (score -2):

I think if you're running the Bay to Breakers sans covering, you're probably naked. If you're on Baker Beach relaxing while the race is going on, you're probably nude. The same person can be both, but probably not at the same time.